# cvLoadImage is returning int?

Tags: c, opencv

According to the OpenCV documentation cvLoadImage must return pointer to IplImage, but it looks like it is returning int.

when I run the below program, i get some warnings which is shown below program

```
#include "highgui.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    IplImage *img = cvLoadImage ("/path/to/file/face.jpg");
    if(img != NULL)
            printf("%d", img->width);
}
```

Also I am getting segmentation fault when I run the above code, I am guessing since img is a int so its causing crash when I am trying to access img->width, Warnings when above code is compiled

```
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.3.0_3/include/opencv2/core/types_c.h:929:13: warning: 
      implicit declaration of function 'cvRound' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    ipt.x = cvRound(point.x);
            ^
    main.c:7:21: warning: implicit declaration of function 'cvLoadImage' is invalid
          in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        IplImage *img = cvLoadImage ("/path/to/file/face.jpg");
                        ^
    main.c:7:15: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing
          'IplImage *' (aka 'struct _IplImage *') with an expression of type 'int'
          [-Wint-conversion]
        IplImage *img = cvLoadImage ("/path/to/file/face.jpg");
```

**warning says incompatible converstion from int**, so I have change the IplImage to int and it worked fine and it ourputs some negative integer value for img

```
#include "highgui.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("%s\n","hello world");
    int img = cvLoadImage ("/path/to/file/face.jpg");
    printf("%d", img);
}
```

I get the below warnings for the above program

```
implicit declaration of function 'cvRound' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    ipt.x = cvRound(point.x);
            ^
main.c:7:15: warning: implicit declaration of function 'cvLoadImage' is invalid
      in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    int img = cvLoadImage ("/path/to/file/face.jpg");
```

I went sleepless to figure out it, google could not help, is it something to do with OpenCV versions or C versions?, I am using Opencv2 3.3.0, please feel free to ask if any information is required

Comment: You're missing a header file (forward declaration for the function).

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh, might be but don't know which one

Comment: did you try adding `cv.h`?

Comment: yes, still getting that implicit declaration warning, i tried way before

Comment: Can you show your compilation statement?

Comment: gcc main.c -o opencv `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv` -ldl -lm

Comment: I'm not very sure, and this is not a very good way, but you can try adding all standarard opencv headers, like `#include "cxtypes.h"
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include "cvaux.h"
#include "cxmisc.h"`...see that if it solvs the poroblem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153011/discussion-between-murali-krish-and-sourav-ghosh).

Comment: I am getting no warning or error in your first code snippet and the second code snippet gives illegal conversion between `IplImage` and `int`.

Comment: cvLoadImage takes two args.

Comment: You seem to be just starting out. Are you sure you want to use such an old version as v2.3 and the old `C` interface? Most of the community has moved on to the much simpler `C++` interface and v3.x

Comment: In version 3.3.0 `cvLoadImage` is not in `highgui` module, it's in imgcodecs -- perhaps `#include "opencv2/imgcodecs/imgcodecs_c.h"`?

Comment: @DanMašek it worked when I included the header, thanks

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am writing the c code for java native interface in Android, I have to do it in C for performance reasons, it looks OpenCV is initially implemented in C programming, and C++, python and Java versions are just wrappers around the initial one

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the first code and should run fine if compiled with g++ instead of gcc.

The second code you're implicitly converting from `IplImage*` to `int` which is wrong and will not run.

The warning and errors regarding `cvRound()` function has to do with OpenCV C API which hasn't been updated in a while and will most likely be removed in a future version. Most of the new OpenCV functionalities are only present in the C++ API.

Other posts which have mentioned errors regarding `cvRound()` function in the C API:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6076

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/8438

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/8658

In the future try to use OpenCV C++ API for best possible results.